# Terminology of a space in real-analysis

Tags: terminology

Since this is a very simple question, i didn't want ask this here not to bother you, so i saw wikipedia and googled this but still don't get what this space is called..

I want to know (i)name, (ii)abbreviation and (iii)Latex of this space. (i.e. (i)Real Number (ii)$\mathbb{R}$ (iii)$\text{ \mathbb{R}}$)

Here it is;

$A(X)$ is a set of all complex-valued, continuous, bounded functions with domain $X$ where $X$ is a metric space.

What is this $A(X)$ called?
Thank you in advance..

Comment: Usually $C(X)$ denotes the continuous $\Bbb C$ valued functions, I'm not aware of any specific name, and somehow you should also express boundedness, it is usually done by a subscript 'b'.

Comment: On [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_functions_on_a_compact_Hausdorff_space) they denote this space by $C_B(X)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Continuous" only refers to the topology so there's no reason to restrict yourself to the case of metric spaces. My understanding is that the standard notation is $C_b(X)$ ($C$ for continuous, $b$ for bounded, and the complex is implied). With the sup norm this is a [C*-algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2A-algebra), isomorphic via the [Gelfand representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfand_representation) to the C*-algebra $C(\beta X)$ of all continuous complex-valued functions on the [Stone-Čech compactification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93%C4%8Cech_compactification) of $X$.